# How to avoid to insert same data into database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

There is one database name as `email_book` and in that database there is one table named as `contact_book`.`name` and `mail_id` are the two column which I had been created in that table.

Now I want to add data into to my table using form in C# but on the counter part I just want to avoid inserting the repeated data into the table. When user add same `mail_id` which is already present in the table then it must gives the message that:

> this mail_address is already present in database

So for that I need coding in C#.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't write code for you. Show your effort first. And if you stuck somewhere, come back. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. As others have said you should try these yourself first. This will give you confidence as well.

Anyways, I am not aware of mysql syntax so I will be providing sql server pseudo code.

I am assuming that you are using a stored procedure to insert data. So in the stored procedure check if the record for the mail_id exist, if yes then return your custom message else insert record and return "record inserted successfully". For example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE your_Proc
(
     @mail_id nvarchar(255),
     ... //other parameters here
)
AS
BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM contact_book WHERE LOWER(mail_id) = LOWER(@mail_id))
      BEGIN
          SELECT "mail id exist"
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO contact_book ....
          SELECT "record inserted successfully"
      END
END
```

In sql server, you can use out parameter as well instead of select to return the message but not sure about mysql.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir..............you provide me accurate code for which i have been looking for.............thanx a lot sir

Comment: Please mark as answer and/or upvote the answer if it was useful. :)